# When Zend_Form validation, validate and find an error all the jQuery hidden fields show up?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, zend-form, show-hide

I am using `Zend_Form` and form validation. The issue is I am hiding some of the form fields using jQuery `show()` and `hide()` functions.

The problem here is that if the validation finds an error, all the form fields will show up and what I want is to keep the state of the hidden and visible fields. Any idea why this is happening?

If the code makes a difference please ask for it I will provide it immediately.

`Zend_Form` code:

```
$this->setMethod('post');

$element = new Zend_Form_Element_File("file", array(
    'validators' => array(
        array('Extension', true, 'hume')
    )
));
$element->setDestination("/var/www/testGraduationProject1/public/TempFolder/");
$element->setLabel("Upload");
$this->addElement($element);

$this->addElement('submit', 'Upload', array(
    'ignore' => true,
    'label' => 'Upload',
));

$this->addElement('select', 'Work_Space', array(
    'Multioptions' =>
        array(
            'Hume_Compile_Selection' => 'Please Select Compiling type',
            'Hume_Recourses' => 'Hume Recourses',
            'Hume_Compile' => 'Hume Compile',
        ),
    'id' => 'Work_Space',
    'label' => 'Compiler'
));

$this->addElement('select', 'Editor', array(
    'Multioptions' =>
        array(
            'Choose Editor' => 'Choose Editor',
            'TinyMce' => 'TinyMce',
            'Ymacs' => 'Ymacs',
        ),
    'id' => 'Editor',
    'label' => 'Editor'
));

$this->addElement('text', 'File_Name', array(
    'label' => 'File name',
    'required' => true,
));

$this->addElement('checkbox', 'Advanced_Settings', array(
    'checked' => '0',
    'label' => 'Advanced Settings',
    'id' => 'Advanced_Settings',
));

$this->addElement('textarea', 'Advanced_Options', array(
    'label' => 'Advanced Options',
    'cols' => 50,
    'rows' => 7,
    'id' => 'Advanced_Options',
    'validators' => array(
        array('regex', true, array(
            'pattern' => '/[^[a-zA-Z ><+.,!@#$%^&*()\"\'=]/',
            'messages' => 'Please only numbers without spaces'
            )
        )
    ),
    'attribs' => array('disabled' => 'disabled'),
));

$this->addElement('textarea', 'comment', array(
    'label' => 'Hume Code',
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'markItUp',
    'id' => 'comment'
));

$this->addElement('checkbox', 'Few_Compile', array(
    'checked' => '1',
    'label' => 'Fewer Results',
    'class' => 'Fewer_Results'
));

$this->addElement('submit', 'Compile_Recourses', array(
    'ignore' => true,
    'label' => 'Compile Recourses',
    'class' => 'Compile_Recourses'
));

$this->addElement('radio', 'Time_Out', array(
    'label' => 'Compiling Time',
    'multiOptions' => array(
         '5' => '5s',
         '10' => '10s',
         '15' => '15s',
     ),
     'value' => array('5s' => '5s')
));

$this->addElement('checkbox', 'Compile_Advanced', array(
    'checked' => '0',
    'label' => "Set Heap Wire Stack Size's",
    'id' => 'Compile_Advanced',
));

$this->addElement('textarea', 'Heap_Size', array(
    'label' => 'Heap Size',
    'Id' => 'Heap-Size',
    'cols' => 5,
    'rows' => 1,
    'validators' => array(
        array('regex', true, array(
            'pattern' => '/[0-9]/',
            'messages' => 'Please only numbers without spaces'
            )
        )
    ),
    'attribs' => array('disabled' => 'disabled'),
));

$this->addElement('textarea', 'Wire_Heap_Size', array(
    'label' => 'Wire_Heap Size',
    'Id' => 'Wire-Heap-Size',
    'cols' => 5,
    'rows' => 1,
    'validators' => array(
        array('regex', false, array(
            'pattern' => '/[0-9]/',
            'messages' => 'Please only numbers without spaces'
            )
        )
    ),
    'attribs' => array('disabled' => 'disabled'),
));

$this->addElement('textarea', 'Stack_Size', array(
    'label' => 'Stack Size',
    'Id' => 'Stack-Size',
    'cols' => 5,
    'rows' => 1,
    'validators' => array(
        array('regex', false, array(
            'pattern' => '/[0-9]/',
            'messages' => 'Please only numbers without spaces'
            )
        )
    ),
    'attribs' => array('disabled' => 'disabled'),
));

$this->addElement('submit', 'Execute_Hume', array(
    'ignore' => true,
    'label' => 'Execute And Compile Hume',
));

$this->addElement('submit', 'Compile_Hume', array(
    'ignore' => true,
    'label' => 'Compile Hume',
));

// die($this->UserHasId);
if ($this->UserHasId) {
    $this->addElement('submit', 'Save_File', array(
        'ignore' => true,
        'label' => 'Save File',
    ));
}
```

jQuery `hide()` and `show()` functions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){              
        $("#Advanced_Settings").click(function(){

            if ($('#Advanced_Settings').is(':checked')) {
                $('#Advanced_Options').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#Few_Compile').attr("disabled", "disabled");

            } else {
                $('#Advanced_Options').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#Few_Compile').removeAttr('disabled');
            }  
        });     
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){              
        $("#Compile_Advanced").click(function(){

            if ($('#Compile_Advanced').is(':checked')) {
                $('#Heap_Size').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#Wire_Heap_Size').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#Stack_Size').removeAttr('disabled');


            } else {
                $('#Heap_Size').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#Wire_Heap_Size').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#Stack_Size').attr("disabled", "disabled");

            }  
        });     
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var WorkSpace = $("#Work_Space").val();
        if(WorkSpace == "Hume_Compile_Selection"){

            $('#Time_Out-label').hide();
            $('#Time_Out-element').hide();
            $('#Compile_Advanced-label').hide();
            $('#Compile_Advanced-element').hide();              
            $('#Heap_Size-label').hide();
            $('#Heap_Size-element').hide();
            $('#Wire_Heap_Size-label').hide();
            $('#Wire_Heap_Size-element').hide();
            $('#Stack_Size-label').hide();
            $('#Stack_Size-element').hide();
            $('#Compile_Hume-element').hide();
            $('#Execute_Hume').hide();

            $('#Advanced_Settings-label').hide();
            $('#Advanced_Settings-element').hide();
            $('#Advanced_Options-label').hide();
            $('#Advanced_Options-element').hide();
            $('#Few_Compile-label').hide();
            $('#Few_Compile-element').hide();
            $('#Compile_Recourses-label').hide();
            $('#Compile_Recourses-element').hide();
        }
        $("#Work_Space").change(function(){
            var WorkSpace = $(this).val();
            if(WorkSpace == "Hume_Recourses"){

                $('#Time_Out-label').hide();
                $('#Time_Out-element').hide();
                $('#Compile_Advanced-label').hide();
                $('#Compile_Advanced-element').hide();              
                $('#Heap_Size-label').hide();
                $('#Heap_Size-element').hide();
                $('#Wire_Heap_Size-label').hide();
                $('#Wire_Heap_Size-element').hide();
                $('#Stack_Size-label').hide();
                $('#Stack_Size-element').hide();
                $('#Compile_Hume-element').hide();
                $('#Execute_Hume').hide();

                $('#Advanced_Settings-label').show();
                $('#Advanced_Settings-element').show();
                $('#Advanced_Options-label').show();
                $('#Advanced_Options-element').show();
                $('#Few_Compile-label').show();
                $('#Few_Compile-element').show();
                $('#Compile_Recourses-label').show();
                $('#Compile_Recourses-element').show();
            }else if(WorkSpace == "Hume_Compile"){
                $('#Time_Out-label').show();
                $('#Time_Out-element').show();
                $('#Compile_Advanced-label').show();
                $('#Compile_Advanced-element').show();              
                $('#Heap_Size-label').show();
                $('#Heap_Size-element').show();
                $('#Wire_Heap_Size-label').show();
                $('#Wire_Heap_Size-element').show();
                $('#Stack_Size-label').show();
                $('#Stack_Size-element').show();
                $('#Compile_Hume-element').show();
                $('#Execute_Hume').show();

                $('#Advanced_Settings-label').hide();
                $('#Advanced_Settings-element').hide();
                $('#Advanced_Options-label').hide();
                $('#Advanced_Options-element').hide();
                $('#Few_Compile-label').hide();
                $('#Few_Compile-element').hide();
                $('#Compile_Recourses-label').hide();
                $('#Compile_Recourses-element').hide();
            }else if(WorkSpace == "Hume_Compile_Selection"){
                $('#Time_Out-label').hide();
                $('#Time_Out-element').hide();
                $('#Compile_Advanced-label').hide();
                $('#Compile_Advanced-element').hide();              
                $('#Heap_Size-label').hide();
                $('#Heap_Size-element').hide();
                $('#Wire_Heap_Size-label').hide();
                $('#Wire_Heap_Size-element').hide();
                $('#Stack_Size-label').hide();
                $('#Stack_Size-element').hide();
                $('#Compile_Hume-element').hide();
                $('#Execute_Hume').hide();

                $('#Advanced_Settings-label').hide();
                $('#Advanced_Settings-element').hide();
                $('#Advanced_Options-label').hide();
                $('#Advanced_Options-element').hide();
                $('#Few_Compile-label').hide();
                $('#Few_Compile-element').hide();
                $('#Compile_Recourses-label').hide();
                $('#Compile_Recourses-element').hide();
            }
        });     
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var count = 0;
        var Editor = $("#Editor").val();
        if(Editor == "Choose Editor"){

            $('#File_Name-label').hide();
            $('#File_Name-element').hide();
            $('#File_Name').hide();

            $('#comment-label').hide();
            $('#comment-element').hide();            
            $('#comment').hide();           
            $('#iframe-ymacs').hide();

            $('#ymacs-use').hide(); 
        }
        $("#Editor").change(function(){
            var Editor = $(this).val();
            if(Editor == "TinyMce"){

                $('#File_Name-label').show();
                $('#File_Name-element').show();            
                $('#File_Name').show();

                $('#comment-label').show();
                $('#comment-element').show();            
                $('#comment').show();

                $('#iframe-ymacs').hide();
                $('#ymacs-use').hide(); 

                $('#accordionResizer').show(); 
                if(count != 0){
                    $('#comment').hide();
                    $('#comment_parent').show();
                }

                if(count == 0){
                    $('#comment-label').show();
                    $('#comment-element').show();            
                    $('#comment').show();
                    tinyMCE.init({

                        // General options
                        mode : "exact",
                        elements : "comment",
                        theme : "advanced",
                        skin : "o2k7",
                        skin_variant : "black",
                        plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
                        save_onsavecallback : "saveContent",

                        // Theme options
                        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull", 
                        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,forecolor,backcolor", 
                        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "hr,removeformat,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,|,print,|,fullscreen,code", 
                        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top", 
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left", 
                        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom", 
                        theme_advanced_resizing : false,

                        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
                        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
                        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
                        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
                        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

                        // Replace values for the template plugin
                        template_replace_values : {
                            username : "Some User",
                            staffid : "991234"
                        }       
                    });
                    count++;
                }

            }else if(Editor == "Choose Editor"){

                $('#File_Name-label').hide();
                $('#File_Name-element').hide();            
                $('#File_Name').hide();

                $('#comment-label').hide();
                $('#comment-element').hide();            
                $('#comment').hide();

                $('#iframe-ymacs').hide();
                $('#ymacs-use').hide(); 
                $('#accordionResizer').show();
            }else if(Editor == "Ymacs"){
                $('#File_Name-label').show();
                $('#File_Name-element').show();            
                $('#File_Name').show();

                $('#comment-label').hide();
                $('#comment-element').hide();            
                $('#comment').hide();

                $('#iframe-ymacs').show();
                //$('#iframe-ymacs').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
                // document.getElementById("#iframe-ymacs").contentDocument.location.reload(true);
                //var iframe = document.getElementById("#iframe-ymacs");
                //alert(iframe);
                // iframe.src = iframe.src;
                jQuery.each($("#iframe-ymacs"), function() {
                    $(this).attr({
                        src: $(this).attr("/index/editor")
                    });
                });
                $('#iframe-ymacs').attr('src', '/index/editor'); 
                $('#ymacs-use').show(); 
                $('#accordionResizer').hide();
                //autoResize('#ymacs');
                //$('#accordionResizer').hide(); 
            }
        });     
    });
</script>
```

Comment: A thing you can try is to put AFTER the form this line $("#Compile_Advanced").click(); . So you'll trigger the event click after the form is found in the code. This should solve the problem

Comment: I didn't understand you where do you mean after the form ???

Comment: <form>...</form> <script>form goes here</script>

Comment: no nothing happened the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, the form is posted, validated server side and when it has errors, it is populated and sent back to the user.  Then, the user sees the form with the error message, am I right?  If that is the case, you will need to trigger your Advanced_Settings and Compile_Advanced checkboxes to check if it should be displayed or not.  Something like:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){              
            $("#Advanced_Settings").click(function(){

                if ($('#Advanced_Settings').is(':checked')) {
                    $('#Advanced_Options').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('#Few_Compile').attr("disabled", "disabled");

                } else {
                    $('#Advanced_Options').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $('#Few_Compile').removeAttr('disabled');
                }  
            }); 

        $('#Advanced_Settings').click();  //This should trigger you checkbox click event
        });

</script>
```

That should hide your advanced settings if the checkbox was not clicked when the form was first submitted.